# SimpleFormatter ignoring the java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format property

Tags: java, logging, glassfish, glassfish-4, java.util.logging

I'm using java.util.logging on GlassFish 4.

I'm defining my own class to initialize the `LogManager` by defining the System property: 
`-Djava.util.logging.config.class`.

My class loads the `logging.properties` file, merges it with some other property file and does some custom replacement.

The following is the relevant part of my `logging.properties` file:

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=C:/Work/server/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/JMSFileHandler%g.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=2000000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=20
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append=true
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$tY:%1$tm:%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS|%4$s: %2$s%n%5$s%n%6$s%n
```

I'm using the standard `FileHandler` and configuring it to use the `SimpleFormatter` as the formatter.

But the `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format` String is being totally ignored. Instead SimpleFormatter uses its default format.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was assuming that the System Property `java.util.logging.config.file` is set by GF from the beginning. This is not the case.

After some investigation I realized that the `LogManager` is initialized two times. In the first time that property doesn't exist, the second time it does.

I was getting an error on the first initialization because I was counting on that property, therefore I didn't initialize the `LogManager` properly, causing the `SimpleFormatter` to use the default format.

I fixed this by changing my code and no longer counting on that System property. This solved the issue.

GF still sets the System property `java.util.logging.config.file` later.

Comment: If it was set after it was loaded that would be a problem.  You might be able to install a security manager and trace where it is being set.

Answer (score 2):

From the [SimpleFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html) docs you have to test for the following conditions:

1. If this property is not defined or the given format string is illegal, the default format is implementation-specific.
2. If this property is set in both the logging properties and system properties, the format string specified in the system property will be used.
3. This property can be defined in the logging properties configuration file.

Here is a sample test case that you can convert and run under GlassFish.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String format = "%1$tY:%1$tm:%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS|%4$s: %2$s%n%5$s%n%6$s%n";
    final String key = "java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format";
    test(format);
    test(System.getProperty(key, format));
    test(LogManager.getLogManager().getProperty(key));
    FileHandler f = new FileHandler();
    System.out.println(f.getFormatter());
    f.close();
}

private static void test(String format) {
    LogRecord record = new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "");
    System.out.println(String.format(format,
                         new java.util.Date(record.getMillis()),
                         record.getSourceClassName(),
                         record.getLoggerName(),
                         record.getLevel().getLocalizedName(),
                         record.getMessage(),
                         String.valueOf(record.getThrown())));
}
```

You also need to check if GlassFish replaced your SimpleFormatter with the 'com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter'.

```
private static void findFormatters() {
    final ArrayList<Handler> handlers = new ArrayList<>();
    final LogManager manager = LogManager.getLogManager();
    synchronized (manager) {
        final Enumeration<String> e = manager.getLoggerNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            final Logger l = manager.getLogger(e.nextElement());
            if (l != null) {
                Collections.addAll(handlers, l.getHandlers());
            }
        }
    }

    for (Handler h : handlers) {
        Formatter f = h.getFormatter();
        System.out.println(h.getClass().getName() + "=" + (f == null ? "" : f.getClass().getName()));
    }
}
```

If you need to check access when the system properties are set you can install a security manager with the [-Djava.security.debug=access,stack](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/java_security_ch1/?page=5) options to trace when the property is set.

Comment: > You also need to check if GlassFish replaced your SimpleFormatter with the 'com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter'.

No, that is not the case

Comment: No System property called "java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format"

Comment: LogManager property "java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format" is exactly the format I specified. Yet the static `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format` is the default format String and not the one I specified.

Comment: SimpleFormatter.format is a static property that is set at Class loading time. Maybe something is using/referencing this class in Code before the LogManager has been loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but it is fixed. I was running my code from an Ant build.xml, and my 
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter.format property was not being applied from my myLogging.properties file, although other properties were read and applied.

Are you using a JRE version < 1.6.32? Java Bug 55052 indicates that the java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter.format property is not properly read from the properties file and applied for earlier versions of the JRE.

See: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55052

I still compile that project with JDK 1.6.24, but run it with JDK 1.7.0.6, and the formatting is properly read and applied to my logger.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see this post is very old, but I had the same problem and I made some discovery regarding this issue.

SimpleFormatter class stores the format property in a static field, so it initialized only once while calling log(…) method. If you call log(…) method before read the configuration, SimpleFormatter class format field is initialized with default values.

The code below works fine:

```
LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(configurationStream);

Logger.getLogger(“logger name”).info(“message”);
```

But code below uses a default formatting (ignores the configuration):

```
Logger.getLogger(“logger name”).info(“message”);

LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(configurationStream);

Logger.getLogger(“logger name”).info(“message”);

Logger.getLogger(“logger name”).info(“message”);
```