# SimpleFormatter dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm:ss

Tags: java, logging

I want to change the way my log looks (java.util.logging.Logger) and I found this:

```
System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format","[%1$tF %1$tT] [%4$-7s] %5$s %n");
```

So my log entries look now like this:

```
[2017-08-24 15:55:40] [INFORMATION] Hello World!
```

I'd like to set the format to following:

```
[24.08.2017 15:55:40]
```

I've been trying for so long, shouldn't be that hard. Can anybody help me or sending me some good and easy documentations/examples?

Comment: why dont you use log4j and use a config file for that???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From documentation [Class Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dt)

Instead of :

```
[%1$tF %1$tT]
```

You can use :

```
[%1$te.%1$tm.%1$tY %1$tT]
```

---

You can see the result in this example :

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String example = String.format("[%1$te.%1$tm.%1$tY %1$tT]", c);
System.out.println(example);
```

Output

```
[24.08.2017 15:19:30]
```

Answer (score 2):

> I've been trying for so long, shouldn't be that hard.

[SimpleFormatter.format is a static property that is set at class loading time.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532155/simpleformatter-ignoring-the-java-util-logging-simpleformatter-format-property)  You can only use [System.setProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) to change the format if that is done before the `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter` class is loaded. Instead you should modify your `logging.properties` or modify your startup script to set the property during the JVM startup.

If there is an error in your format the behavior is to just use a default format.  This makes it hard to debug because you can't tell the difference between an error or just not setting the property correctly.

Your best bet is to use a test program like `YCF_L` made and then apply the format to the startup script.